# Inconsistent Input Behavior with PointerInput on iOS 17 using Appium Java Client and Selenium

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I am currently working with iOS 17 and the Appium Java Client version 8.5.0. My goal is to enter three numbers into a numeric field by simulating key presses using the PointerInput class.

Here's the scenario: I'm attempting to use the keyboard to click the numbers 1, 2, and 3, which correspond to the following coordinates on the screen:

Number 1: Button at position (0,561)
Number 2: Button at position (125,561)
Number 3: Button at position (262,561)
However, I'm experiencing inconsistent input behavior. Instead of obtaining the expected sequence of '123', the output I'm getting is '11122'. This occurs despite having experimented with different durations for the pauses between inputs.

No matter how I adjust the pauses, there seems to be no improvement, and the issue persists where the input is erratic and includes more numbers than intended. It's unclear whether the issue lies with the PointerInput implementation or if there's a specific iOS 17 interaction that I'm not accounting for.

```
public void fasterPINLogin(String numbersText) {
PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
Sequence tap = new Sequence(finger, 0);

if (isIOS()) {
    clicks(finger, tap,0,561);
    clicks(finger, tap,128,561);
    clicks(finger, tap,262,561);
    iosDriver.perform(List.of(tap));
  }
 } 
 private void clicks(PointerInput finger, Sequence tap, int x, int y) {
      tap.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(ofMillis(10), 
      PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), x, y));
      tap.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(LEFT.asArg()));
      tap.addAction(new Pause(finger, ofMillis(500)));
      tap.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(LEFT.asArg()));
      tap.addAction(new Pause(finger, ofMillis(500)));
  }`
```